# How to handle exceptions inside async block java

Tags: java, playframework

I am making 2 https requests one after the other. I want to return with error state in case 1st request fails before making another request.

```
private CompletionStage<WSResponse> reverseGeocode(Double latitude, Double longitude) throws AuthenticationException {
    WSRequest complexRequest = ws.url(SECO_URL);

    return complexRequest.post(GRANT_TYPE + "=" + PASSWORD + "&" + USERNAME + "=" + SECO_USERNAME + "&" + PASSWORD
            + "=" + SECO_PASSWORD)
            .thenCompose(res -> {
                String authToken;
                try {
                    authToken = res.asJson().findValue("access_token").toString().replace("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage() + e.toString());
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Not able to authenticate user");
                }
                String url = configuration.getString("host.lbsUrl") + "/rgc/json?lat=" 
                        + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude;
                WSRequest requestToReverseGeocode = ws.url(url)
                        .setHeader(API_KEY, ST_SECO_X_API_KEY)
                        .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE)
                        .setHeader(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + authToken);
                return requestToReverseGeocode.get();
            });

}
```

Above function gives me error that authentication error is unhandled. How do I return the error in this case?

Above code doesnt compile and the error is

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[unreported exception org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown]
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:49)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:17)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayRun.scala:61)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:339)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:44)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:40)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:337)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:118)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:405)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exceptionally` to catch any errors that may arise.

```
return complexRequest.post()
    .thenCompose(res -> {
        if (someCondition) throw new Step1Exception("Step 1 failed");
        // (...)    
    }).thenCompose(res -> {
        if (someAnotherCondition) throw new StepNException("Step N failed");
        // (...)    
    }).exceptionally(e -> ok("Got an error: " + e.getMessage()));
```

Notice that if `someCondition` is true, the second `thenCompose` is not executed.

Comment: My return value for the function is completionStage<WSResponse> and I get the compilation error "cannot convert string into wsresponse"

Comment: @raju You are returning a string somewere instead of the wsresponse. Can you post the code (if are still having this problem)?